# Изменение connectionStrings на форме

Tags: c#

```
private void setButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["WinDrawModel"].ConnectionString = this.serverlName.Text;
    config_.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
}
```

Делаю изменение конфигурационных параметров, в папке Debug появляется конфигурационный файл такого рода ComplexWorkWinDraw.exe.Config однако сам App.config не меняется. Интересует причина такого. Спасибо

Comment: а почему `App.config` должен меняться?

Comment: Я это и хотел выяснить

Comment: Если вы говорите о том `App.config`, что находится у вас в проекте, ему без разницы, что вы в коде вызываете.

Comment: При перебилдивании - подтягивается все из app.config.

Comment: при перебилдивании студия берет ваш App.Config, копрует его в выходную папку и переименовывает в `ComplexWorkWinDraw.exe.Config`, удаляя при этом предыдущую версию файла `ComplexWorkWinDraw.exe.Config`

Comment: Да, я это уже понял...

Comment: Но я бы хотел сам appconfig менять, в нем из программы

Comment: ваша программа запускается уже после того, как её сбилдили. Соответственно, она не может повлиять на исходные файлы

Comment: Что такое config_? Попробуйте [открыть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx) конфиг уровня PerUserRoamingAndLocal а не None.

Comment: Понял, попробую, спасибо